# Make Visual Studio ignore wwwroot during development but still serve it while debugging

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have an SPA where the API backend is developed in Visual Studio with ASP.NET 6.0
and the frontend is built/packed with rollup. Since Visual Studio should also host the fronend
files, rollup copies them to the subdirectory wwwroot of the Visual Studio project directory.
Every time rollup copies the files to wwwroot, Visual Studio consumes a lot of CPU. It looks
as if it parses all the files, maybe for Intellisense?

This doesn't make sense in this case, however, because the content of wwwroot is the built
output of rollup. Is there any way to tell Visual Studio to ignore these files during development
but still serve them when debugging?

If there are better ways to do this, I appreciate any recommendations.

I'm using Visual Studio 17.4.4

Comment: Have you tried putting `app.UseStaticFiles();` on a non-development environment?

Comment: What do you mean by this? We run the app on many production systems. Once built and published everything is fine. Or do you mean to point app.UseStaticFiles() during development to a directory that is not part of the Visual Studio project directory?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this problem of live analysis.

You can right-click the project node in Solution Explorer and select `Properties`, then select the `Code Analysis` tab, uncheck the `Run on live analysis` option to disable live source analysis.

For more details, youcan refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/disable-code-analysis?view=vs-2022). Hope this can work for you.

Comment: Thanks, a good idea. I tried but it does not help. Looking at the task manager there is always Visual Studio itself and MSBuild that consume most of the cpu. I guess it has nothing to do with code analysis but with the fact that my JS build system rebuilds all the JS files and places them in wwwroot directory. VS and/or MSBuild seem to watch this directory for changes.